# How to access a private field in a class

Tags: javascript

```js
class Movie {
  constructor(movieName, category ) {
    this._movieName = movieName;
    this._category = category;
  }

  showMovieName() {
    return `${movieName}`;
  }
}

const movie1 = new Movie("Avengers", "superheroes");


console.log(movie1.showMovieName());
```

I have a Movie class and two fields with underscores. I need to create a method that returns the title of the movie. How can i do this? Now in the console the error movieName is not defined

Comment: Neither of these is private. They just have an underscore at the beginning. You access them the same way you access any other property from the same class `this._movieName`

Comment: By the way, `\`${x}\`` is superfluous because it's the same as `x` (if `x` is a string, at least).

Comment: Even if you used _actual_ private properties, there’d be no issue in accessing them. `class Movie { #movieName; #category; constructor(movieName, category){ this.#movieName = movieName; this.#category = category; } showMovieName(){ return String(this.#movieName); } }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of your fields are private. Just prefix `movieName` with underscore.

```
showMovieName() {
  return `${this._movieName}`;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you need to change `` return `${movieName}`; `` to `` return `${this._movieName}`; ``

### More info

Your example uses the public field declaration syntax of classes to declare two public instance properties named `_movieName` and `_category`.

Using underscores as property name prefixes is an old-fashioned (although still common) way to indicate that a property is intended to be private (although this approach offers no enforcement whatsoever).

JavaScript now has private class fields. These can be declared using the `#` prefix ("hash name syntax") and cannot be accessed in any way by anything outside of the class body itself.

Private fields are added before the constructor runs and are not inherited.

```js
class Movie {
    #movieName;

    constructor(movieName) {
        this.#movieName = movieName;
    }

    showMovieName() {
        return `${this.#movieName}`;
    }
}

const movie1 = new Movie('Avengers');

console.log(movie1.showMovieName());
```

Answer (score -4):

There are no real private properties in JS at the moment, however, you are trying to access a property so must use `this.`, please see below

```js
class Movie {
  constructor(movieName, category ) {
    this._movieName = movieName;
    this._category = category;
  }

  showMovieName() {
    return `${this._movieName}`;
  }
}

const movie1 = new Movie("Avengers", "superheroes");


console.log(movie1.showMovieName());
```

Comment: We have "private" members; prefixing a member with `#` will make it private.

Comment: There _are_ private fields in JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields